# How can i make script of all store procedures in dbml file

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am working on MVC4 project with linq. I have dbml file which contains all store procedure for that particular database.

Now i want to move my project from test environment to production , so is there any way where i can make sql script to create sp of store procedures present in that dbml file ?

Comment: Why aren't you keeping sources for your sp in a proper SCS?

Comment: You can take help of CreateDatabase method to generate sql script. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399420.aspx

Comment: The source of your SPs is nowhere in the dbml file. Only in the database. This is a dead end.